# Facing special characters in json of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i don't know why special characters are coming , here is my code but first check out the image of special characters [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isfOz.png)

```
$output = [];

foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle) 
{
    $center_lat = $lat;
    $center_lng = $lon;
    $lat=$vehicle->lat;
    $lng=$vehicle->lon;

    $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);
    

    $a_id= $vehicle->a_id;
    $a=DB::table('tbl')->where('id',$a_id)->get();

    $output [$key] = $vehicle;
    $result[] = array_merge((array)$output[$key],(array)$a);

}
return response()->json($result,201);
```

my output is like that

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
         ......
        "distance": 3834.5607952869,
        "0": {"special character":
             [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                     .....
}
]
```

but i want my output in json format like that

```
 [
        {
            "id": 1,
             ......
            "distance": 3834.5607952869,
            "array_name": 
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                         .....
    }
    ]
```

Comment: This will probably have to do with character encodings, like UTF8 or ISO-x, etc
Not sure how your get your input, but if it's trough a rest call, check the headers that came with it, which might hint you, what codepage/encoding should be used.

And you can use json_decode manually with the proper code page.

Comment: then how i will handle this ?

Comment: The (array) casts your are doing, are only casting the first level, you could do a 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Which allows deeper conversion, also the encode allows to to changen encoding options.

However your code, does not tell me how you get your data.
If it's in a total different code page, you might need to convert it with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php before converting it to JSON

Comment: i get data from db like this $vehicles=DB::table('vehicle')->get();

Comment: i think json_decode is for string but i have an array

Comment: Then probaly where it entered DB it was already not matching your DB encoding, that is the place where it probably needs to be fixed.

You can use json_decode / json_encode for, strings, arrays, objects or anything thats serializeable. The advantage is, that it is work recursive / multi dimensional arrays

Comment: and i am getting code in same page

Answer (score 1):

You to make sure that you are converting the collection to an array, like so:

```
foreach ($vehicles as $key => $vehicle)
{
    $center_lat = $lat;
    $center_lng = $lon;
    $lat=$vehicle->lat;
    $lng=$vehicle->lon;

    $vehicle->distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);


    $a_id= $vehicle->a_id;
    $a=DB::table('tbl')->where('id',$a_id)->get()->toArray();

    $output [$key] = $vehicle;
    $result[] = array_merge((array)$output[$key], $a);

}
return response()->json($result,201);
```

The `get()` method for Eloquent ORM via `DB` returns a `Collection` object. So, when you try to convert a class object to an array, you get stray characters that will pop up that cause issues. Just make sure that you use the methods that they provide and it will solve all your issues.

See this documentation for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-toarray